# Incomplete Page Loads in Apache and PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

A client frequently loads our site on his iPhone and has troubles with incomplete page loads.  I also sometimes on my laptop load up the home page and there's issues with our rotator due to an incomplete page load.
A survey of messages, and various logs show no issue I can discern.  But is there a way to in either apache or php make a log of when a page or file isn't completely loaded?

Comment: Check your php log file if you have activated it, an unhandled exception by php will create the symptom you have.

Comment: Since Apache responds with a 200 Status, at that point it just sends the data to the browser. If the page is not loading completely, the browser is not rendering it all, you will need to review the console or use an HTTP reporting tool to see what the browser is doing with the data. Also may need to review `DOCTYPE` of the page that does not load all the way.

Comment: I have checked the php log file and there's nothing like an uncaught error that I can find.

If I can ever get it to load improperly for me then I can use the console.  I'm wondering if it's an issue with our host, and bad routing between the east coast and our server mid load sometimes.